# Invalid cursor state java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I created a program for inserting data into MSAccess Database. When i execute the statements I get an java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state .
The database is empty. I tried to move the cursor to the first row by executing resultSet.next(); but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?? This is my code so far:

Code for creating the connection:

```
    public LogInInterface() {
    initComponents();

      //Database Connection Setup.
      try{
          String Driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
          Class.forName(Driver);
          //ErrorLabel.setText("DRIVER LOADED");
          //ErrorLabel.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
          String Login = "jdbc:odbc:JavaDB";
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Login);
          statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
          resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
          //ErrorLabel.setText("DATABASE CONNECTION IS READY");
          //ErrorLabel.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
          //ErrorLabel.setText(null);


      }catch(Exception e){
          ErrorLabel.setText("DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR (Code 1)");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

Code for inserting into database:

```
 private void RegisterButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO add your code here
    try{
        String FName = FirstNameTextField.getText();
        String LName = LastNameTextField.getText();
        resultSet.moveToInsertRow();
        resultSet.updateString(2,FName );
        resultSet.updateString(3,LName);
        resultSet.updateRow();
        statement.close();
        resultSet.close();
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

    }catch(Exception e1){
        ErrorLabel.setText("ACCOUNT COULD NOT BE CREATED AT THIS TIME (Code 2)");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.setPos(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5271)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.updateRow(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:4171)
at com.company.LogInInterface.RegisterButtonActionPerformed(LogInInterface.java:251)
at com.company.LogInInterface.access$1400(LogInInterface.java:12)
at com.company.LogInInterface$9.actionPerformed(LogInInterface.java:545)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Did you try this, replace your create statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); with statement = connection.createStatement();

Comment: When i enclose my result statement into a if (resultSet.next()){...} I get this exeception :java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed

Comment: leave the connection.createStatement empty or change the flag as manouti did mention.

Comment: I did replace the statement and I get this now : java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Cursor Type: 1003
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.moveToInsertRow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `ResultSet.updateRow` with `ResultSet.insertRow`. From the [Javadoc of `ResultSet.updateRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow()):

> Updates the underlying database with the new contents of the current row of this ResultSet object. *This method cannot be called when the cursor is on the insert row*.

Also look at the Javadoc of [`ResultSet.moveToInsertRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#moveToInsertRow()) which you're calling in the method:

> Moves the cursor to the insert row. The current cursor position is remembered while the cursor is positioned on the insert row. The insert row is a special row associated with an updatable result set. It is essentially a buffer where a new row may be constructed by calling the updater methods prior to inserting the row into the result set. ***Only the updater, getter, and insertRow methods may be called when the cursor is on the insert row***. All of the columns in a result set must be given a value each time this method is called before calling insertRow. An updater method must be called before a getter method can be called on a column value.

Comment: yeah, as it is an insert you should use the proper flag.

Comment: I used resultSet.insertRow() and I get this exeception java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Cursor Type: 1003
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.moveToInsertRow

Comment: Hey i managed to Insert into the database but anyway an exeception is thrown: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.checkOpen(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:6646)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.clearWarnings(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1765)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.close(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:1468) How can I get rid of that?????????

Comment: @EthimjosVelo Please update the original question with your progress and new exceptions or ask another question. As a side note, why are you creating a `ResultSet` twice, once with `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and once with `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`?

Comment: I found it. I should not use  statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);*/ after closing the statement and the result set